# How do I browse a php file in a different directory?

Tags: php, directory

I am trying to search in google for php code that will let me load or browse a file `work2.php`.

Note that my directory is `/home/meria/public_html/work/`.

example: `/home/meria/public_html/work/code.php`

The target file is: `/var/work2.php`

Comment: I don't really understand your question but if you read the file locally with fopen apache will not interpret your php and then you can echo the content of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to include the file?

```
<?php
include "/var/work2.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

If: `/home/meria/public_html/work/code.php`
going to: `/var/work2.php`

```
include "../../../../var/work2.php"; // I might be a little off
```

Comment: I think you need one more `../`, but you should be able to just use the absolute path `include '/var/work2.php';`.

Comment: @Neal: Actually, you had the right number of `../`s, I lied :-P

Comment: @Rocket rrrg, ok i rolled back